# Swift - JSONEncoder on generics

Tags: json, swift, generics

**How can I send generic struct to a function that returns a JSON?**

Im trying to make a func that gets a struct as a parameter and returns a JSON data. Im making it because I want to avoid repetition and it will be used in several places and with different structs (ie: user, client, contact...)

```
struct User : Codable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

func makeJSONData<T>(_ value: T) -> Data {
    var jsonData = Data()
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()

    do {
        jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(value)
    }
    catch {
    }
    return jsonData
}
```

By using makeJSONData, I get an error: *Argument type 'T' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'*

```
let user = User(email: emailTextField.text!, password : passwordTextField.text!)
let user2 = makeJSONData(user)
```

Comment: change method declaration to `func makeJSONData<T: Codable>(_ value: T) -> Data`

Answer (score 2):

because of you don't define the type of T, just change

```
makeJSONData<T>
```

to

```
makeJSONData<T: Codable>
```

Comment: By following Mukesh`s answer, it worked. Quoc Nguyen, there is a typo on your commend.

Comment: @RenanAguiar yeah, fixed it. Thanks